# Stream Closed Error Java

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, huffman-code

I am getting a Stream Closed Error. I am attempting write a huffman tree to a text file but every time I run it, the error pops up saying that the stream has been closed. Any ideas?

```
    HuffmanTree Tree = new HuffmanTree();
    HuffmanTree.HuffData[] freqTable = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try{
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("oddysy.txt"));

    freqTable = HuffmanTree.buildFreqTable(in);
    Tree.buildTree(freqTable);
    Tree.buildCodeTable();
    Tree.printCode(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("freqTable.txt")));

    Tree.encode(in, new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("watsonStructure.txt")));
    } finally {
        if (in != null){
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null){
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(BufferedReader.java:122)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:179)
at HuffmanTree.encode(HuffmanTree.java:244)
at Huffman_Driver.main(Huffman_Driver.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is that you are using a reader which is already done with reading.

In the following code HuffmanTree build the frequency table with the buffered reader.

```
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("oddysy.txt"));
freqTable = HuffmanTree.buildFreqTable(in);
```

Now the BufferedReader read all the data from the file and close the stream since there is no data to read.

Again you are trying to use the same BufferedReader where the reader read all the data from the file and close the stream. Hence you are getting this exception.

```
Tree.encode(in, new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("watsonStructure.txt")));
```

If you need to read the data from the same file, again you have to initialize the BufferedReader.

Comment: I am sorry, still a little confused. So I should close the stream and then reinitialize the BufferedReader? @Erranda

Comment: Once you done reading with a BufferedReader you can't reuse it. If you need to read again from that file just initialize a different BufferedReader. But make sure that you close the readers at some point.